# How to open a new tab in the current window as an admin in Tabby on Windows 10?

Tags: powershell, administrator, tabs, tabby

By default I use [pwsh](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) as the default shell in [Tabby](https://tabby.sh/) how to open a new tab in Tabby using **shortcut key** or **command** as an **administrator**?

### What have I tried

- Searched for this feature in the [Github repo](https://github.com/Eugeny/tabby) but didn't get it.
- Googled about opening new tab in `Tabby` with admin privilege.
- Looked for *Hotkeys* in `Tabby` settings

How can I open a new tab in tabby with **admin privileges**?

Comment: Tabby on which system, Windows?  I assume yes looking at one of earlier questions, but should always include such info if all mentioned apps can run on multiple systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

1. Go to `Settings` -> `Profiles & Connections`
2. Either:

- edit the default `pwsh` profile by single clicking on its row

[image: Row]

- add new profile based on the default `pwsh` one

3. Enable `Run as administrator`:

[image: Run as administrator switch]

4. Choose the edited/added profile as `Default profile for new tabs` in the same menu.

Comment: In which Tabby version?